# JDBC insert Statement not working

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to create a java application that insert data in a database. Application is fairly simple. It take 3 input from user and insert that input to database. Everything working but I get sql error executing insert statement. 
Here is code snippet.

```
sa.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history (to, subject, body)"+"VALUES("+ DATA1 + "','" + DATA2 + "','" +DATA3+ "')'");
```

I am sure I am having problem with the Double Quotes and Single Quotes in statement.

Comment: Please describe "Not Working"? What is the error you see?

Answer (score 6):

You should always use `PreparedStatement`s for this kind of thing. It takes care of quoting for you and protects you from SQL injection attacks:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO history (to, subject, body) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
statement.setString(1, DATA1);
statement.setString(2, DATA2);
statement.setString(3, DATA3);
statement.execute();
```

Not only that, but the database driver can compile and cache prepared statements, potentially making them much more efficient.

Note that the `setString` indices are 1-based, not zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

```
sa.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history (to, subject, body)"+"VALUES("+ DATA1 + "','" + DATA2 + "','" +DATA3+ "')'");
```

This code will produce query like this:

```
INSERT INTO history (to, subject, body)VALUES(vinesh','raja','1111')'
```

You have to remove single quotes after the last ')' and add single quote after 'VALUES'.

Instead try this code:

```
sa.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history (to, subject, body)"+"VALUES('"+ DATA1 + "','" + DATA2 + "','" +DATA3+ "')");
```

Comment: Actually i did 
`code`executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history "+"VALUES('"+ DATA1 + "','" + DATA2 + "','" +DATA3+ "')");

which worked !!
Any wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

As Vinesh Suggested the solution, I would simply like to tell, better you take one variable as

```
String query="SQL QUERY";
then just do System.out.println(query);
```

then run the line,

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
```

so that, you will correctly identify the final query formed.

Answer (score -1):

1.Rather than using String Class use String Buffer or String Builder which is a mutable class. On the other hand, String Class is immutable. You can use String Buffer like

1. `String Buffer stbuffer = new String Buffer();`

   ```
   stbuffer.append("insert into ");
   stbuffer.append("<tablename> ");
   stbuffer.append("<fields >");
   stbuffer.append(" values");
   stbuffer.append("(+");
   stbuffer.append(String);
   stbuffer.append(")");  ....etc
   ```
2. You can get the final string representation using `stbufffer.toString();`
3. You can insert this type of queries to exceute `update()` methods like `ins.executeUpdate(stbuffer.toString);`
4. You can also use it like this for Insert statement and also for  Prepared Statement

Comment: Don't do this, use `PreparedStatement`